# Type 'unknown' is not assignable to other type, when strict mode is true

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, strict, strict-mode

I have type error.
Exists child component `Pagination` with type of props:

```
interface BaseProps {
  url: string;
  rowKey: string;
  renderItem: (item: unknown) => React.ReactNode;
  params?: Record<string, unknown>;
  foundTextSuffix?: string;
  separated?: boolean;
  useLaggy?: boolean;
}
```

In parent component function `renderItem` is passed to child component `Pagination`. This function needed to render other nested components in different places.

```
<Pagination
        url={API.service('search')}
        rowKey="id"
        foundTextSuffix=" services"
        renderItem={({id, shortTitle, organizationTitle}: ServiceExtended) => (
          <ListItem
             title={<Link href={{pathname: '/services/[serviceId]', query: {serviceId: id}}}>{shortTitle}</Link>}
                        subTitle={organizationTitle}
           />
        )}
        params={frozen}
/>
```

Argument of function `renderItem` has type `unknown` in type of `Pagination` component, `strict mode` is true. When I try to pass a function in props of `Pagination` component with argument type `ServiceExtended`, for example, there is type error:

> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ServiceExtended'

I can't list all possible types in argument of `renderItem`, because there are a lot of them, there will be new ones in the future and this approach doesn't work with `strict mode`.
Please, help to find solution

I wrote simple example of my case below. This type error is occurring only with strict mode

```
type childPropType ={
  render: (data: unknown) => JSX.Element
}

type parentPropType = {
  id: number,
  greeting: string
}

const data: parentPropType = {
  id: 1,
  greeting: 'Hello'
}

const Child = (props: childPropType) => {
  const {render} = props;
  return (
    <div>{render(data)}</div>
  )
}

const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child
        render={
          ({id, greeting}: parentPropType) => <div>{greeting}</div>
        }
      />

    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mAj2BW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz ok, I added example of my case in question

Comment: It really looks like you want `ChildPropType` to be generic in the type of the argument to its `render` method, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOJrzW).  If that doesn't work for you, please amend the example to show a failed use case.  If it does work for you I can write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz unfortunately it doesn't work for me, there are a lot of parent components and each parent component  has own unique property and there will be new ones in the future, i wrote another example [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-v32fbf?file=index.tsx)

Comment: You still need it to be generic, but now you have a correlation between `id` and `render`.  Would [*this*](//tsplay.dev/we4yBW) meet your needs? If not, please let me know the problem. If you want type safety, you'll need to give the compiler enough information to know that `Child` will only be called with the right sorts of inputs; `unknown` is way too wide. If you don't care about type safety, then use `any` instead of `unknown` or disable `--strict`. But then you are not going to get any warnings if someone writes `<Child id="second" render={(data:ParentProp1Type)=>data.greeting}/>`.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for your help, I think to disable strict mode for this case

Comment: So what, if anything, do you want to see as an answer to this question?

Comment: @jcalz I thought there is some way to rewrite BaseProps, especially renderItem property, to solve type error without using unknown